# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-{(x-1)}^2} dx$

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-({x-1)}^2} dx$$

I tried polar coordinates
but couldn't apply the right
 variable transformation...

Comment: The same as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-x^2}\,dx$ surely?

Comment: Refer to [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: Change of variable $X=x-1$ and it will work in polar coordinates.

Comment: Start with $u = x-1$ then you have the more familiar Gaussian.